# trigger('click') on a dynamically added link does not propagate for external links in JQM

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-events

I am attempting to use jQuery Mobile's Select Menu in a Navbar as a navigation tool.  It will need to handle both internal and external links.  Binding to `change` enables the use of the `$.mobile.selectmenu()` widget to fetch the selected link which has been built with custom data bits for the URL and locality status.  The link is then dynamically appended to the document and `.trigger('click')` is called.

http://jsfiddle.net/wZNMz/

Regardless of the permutations of binding events, return values, event propagation wrangling, and attributes the external link will not work.  The internal link works just fine.

Referring to the [jquery.mobile.navigation.js source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/js/jquery.mobile.navigation.js#L1287) triggering **click** should work as expected assuming the `[rel='external']` is matched to enable default URL handling.  Note that the plugin strips links out of `<option>` tags on init requiring all the hackiness of adding a link and triggering click on a `<select>` change.

The dirty and obvious hack is to set `window.location` when external and be done.  This does work but I can't see why it should be necessary to resort to that.  Any thoughts or insights are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a link and triggering a click on it seems a lot more hacky than using `window.location`, which is there for this specific reason, to forward users to a new page. For internal links you can route the request through `$.mobile.changePage()`. Here is an example:

```
$('#mobile-nav').bind('change', function(e) {
    var nav_to = $(this).selectmenu('selected');

    if (nav_to.data('locality') === false) {
        //this is external, so use window.location
        window.location = nav_to.data('item-url');
    } else {
        //this is internal, so use $.mobile.changePage()
        $.mobile.changePage(nav_to.data('item-url'), {
            //here you can set options such as transition type and direction
        });
    }
});
```

Here is the documentation for `$.mobile.changePage()`: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/methods.html

Comment: You are right - not sure what I was going for but this solution fit my needs well.  Thanks!